# eclipse plugin : How to create org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType from the datatype of org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.FieldDeclaration?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

Using ASTParser I am parsing a class. Now my goal is to modify the class of one of the field.The field is available as FieldDeclaration now I want to create IType from the data type of  FieldDeclaration.

example:
    class Dog{
   private Collar c;
   }

Here "private Collar c" is already available as FieldDeclaration .How is it possible to create IType of "Collar"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several steps that you need to follow here.  I am going to sketch out the solution. But, I'll leave it up to you to figure out the final code to write.

The first thing to realize is that the `IType` classes and the `FieldDeclaration` classes are created in different ways and are used to do different things. `IType` and related interfaces are used to look at the structure of an entire program.  Whereas `FieldDeclartion` and related classes are part of the Java DOM and used to look at the structure of a single file. If the class you are working with is not inside of a proper Java project in Eclipse, then there will be no IType to create.

So, here is what you do:

1. ASTParser parser = ASTParser.create(AST.JLS8);
2. parser.setResolveBindings(true);
3. CompilationUnit unit = parser.parse(...);
4. get your fieldDeclaration
5. String name = fieldDeclaration.getType().resolveBinding().getQualifiedName();
6. IJavaProject project = JavaCore.create(IProject);  // pass in the resource correspoding to the project in which this is based
7. IType type = project.findType(name);

Not easy, but following these steps should work. I can provide clarification on steps if you need them.